# Cannot click UI button in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am working on Unity 5.4. I have an Event System, my UI has a parent canvas, Canvas has the graphic raycaster. I am not able to understand why this is not working. I have attached an image of the button script, Canvas, event system and my script.

[image: My Inspector Views]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Level01Controller : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private int highScore ;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit ();
            Debug.Log ("Clicked);
        }
    }

    public void StartGame()
    { 
        Application.LoadLevel ("Level01_Game");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you called the method from `OnClick` of the button?

Comment: Can you show us your Start Button inspector with the Transform and Button components expanded? Also, it's generally preferred to paste & format code as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: Please check the updates on the question

Comment: I notice you've unchecked the "interactable" checkbox on the button... Are you re-enabling it from a script anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your button is not interactable

As mentioned by *DMGregory*, you have "interactable" unchecked on your button script. This tells the button it is *not* interactive. Replicating your setup with your code, I can confirm that once you check this box, your code runs as intended.

We can see the button working through my debug log; instead of changing levels, I get an error, as I have not actually set up "Level01_Game" as a scene. I have also included a `Debug.Log()` output in the `StartGame()` method, for clarity.

[image: With "Interactable" checked, the button works.]

### Other potential issues

While seemingly unrelated to your user interface, there are some other issues with your setup that might lead to problems. While we can not actually see if some of these problems actually exist, I will mention all possible issues, just in case.

#### Close your strings!!

You have a `Debug.Log()` in your `Update()` method, where you are sending in "`"Clicked`". It ***should*** be "`"Clicked"`", and it is *imperative* you see the difference.

Without the closing quotation marks, `Clicked` will probably not be interpreted as a string. In my compiler, it interprets as a value type. Minor errors like this can present much larger problems, as they throw such ambiguous errors, that the compiler will *often* point you in the wrong direction with its error output. In this case, it does not *appear* to be that bad. My compiler reports the error only a mere 4 characters later, when it detects the end of the line without an actual closing bracket; the `);` on the end is still being interpreted as part of the string, and is not seen as actual code.

Of course, the result may be different, depending on the compiler you use. In my case, the error thrown physically prevents me from being able to play test, to begin with. If your compiler does not raise this issue, you may have run into much more perplexing problems later on, when hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> caused your program to have *very* weird behavior.

#### Input buttons must be setup

You have added a `StandaloneInputModule` through your `EventSystem`. Your `StandaloneInputModule` lists two axis and two buttons. In the given case, they are set to the defaults of *Horizontal*, *Vertical*, *Submit* and *Cancel*. These values *must* correspond to available axis and buttons via your general Input Manager. While their functionality does not directly relate to the button you have set up, the errors thrown from your input not being setup will prevent further functionality, *including* your button. You can access your Input Manager via the top menu, by selecting **Edit > Project Settings > Input**. Just having the correct input of the same name is enough to fix this error.

[image: Input Manager with 4 axes: Horizontal, Vertical, Submit and Cancel.]

#### `Application.LoadLevel` is obsolete

`Application.LoadLevel` has been marked as `obsolete`, as it has been replaced with `SceneManager.LoadLevel`. Using it might cause other problems; I currently use Unity 5.3.5, and have previously been *unable* to use `Application.LoadLevel` for the same reason.

This is actually *good* news. We now have an actual [Scene Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) class to handle our scenes, so using it directly is just good house keeping. Just make sure that you include the required library, by including `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the top of your script.

Apart from that, the two methods are identical in context of your implementation. Instead of `Application.LoadLevel("Level01_Game")`, you would call `SceneManager.LoadScene("Level01_Game")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, for pointing out my errors and also for suggesting better ways :)